# Simple regular expression not matching number in Python3

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to match a number between 1 and 3 in a string using a regex:

```py
import re

print(re.match(r'[1-3]{1}', 'a1')) # Prints None
print(re.match(r'[1-3]{1}', '1a')) # Prints <re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='1'>
```

While my regex seems to be working correctly both on regex101.com and in JS, for some reason I cannot get it to work in Python3.

Can someone point me to what is wrong here?

Comment: Thanks @wiktor-stribiżew for the answer :)

Comment: Use `re.search`. BTW, `print(re.match(r'[1-3]{1}', '1a'))` [does not print None](https://ideone.com/nPp2C8).

Comment: Thanks, I'll update the question!

Comment: `{1}` is a redundant quantifier in regex, synonymous with having nothing in its place.